# How to plot surface fit through 3D data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, 3d, plotly

I have a 3D scatter plot that renders like this:

[image]

The 3D dataset is very big, so I can't include it here. One can try and answer this using the standard datasets like `mtcars` or `iris`.

My attempt to plot this 3D scatterplot:

```
x <- rbind(A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3) 
fig1 <- x %>% plot_ly(x= ~x,y=~y,z = ~z, color= ~key,type="scatter3d", size = 0.5)
fig1
```

`A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3` are different 3*n `dataframes` which are combined together using `rbind` and differentiated by using the key included in each `dataframe`

I tried fitting the surface by various methods like `add_surface()`, `add_trace()`, changing the type to `'mesh3D'`

But, the resultant surface fit is not what I want, I need a smooth surface fitting through this scatter data. The error I am getting is this: `z is not a numeric matrix.`

Is there any better way of fitting the surface, what am I missing here?

P.S. I would prefer rendering the plot with `ggplot()`, `plot_ly()`, `ggplotly()`.

Comment: I have posted a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372502/problem-in-plotting-gam-model-surface-fit-through-plotly-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fit a model first using something like `gam()` and then plot the predictions.  First, we can fit the GAM to the data. In this case, `hp` and `wt`are the two independent variables (i.e., the `x` and `y` axes of the chart above).  `qsec` is the variable plotted on the z-axis and is the dependent variable in the model.

```
data(mtcars)
library(mgcv)
mod <- gam(qsec ~ te(hp) + te(wt) + ti(hp, wt), data=mtcars)
```

Next, we need to make some predictions for the model at different combinations of `hp` and `wt`.  The easiest way to do this is to make a sequence of values for each variable that goes from their minima to their maxima.  This is what the commands below do.  It makes a sequence of 25 evenly spaced values going from the minimum to the maximum of each independent variable.

```
hp.seq <- seq(min(mtcars$hp, na.rm=TRUE), max(mtcars$hp, na.rm=TRUE), length=25)
wt.seq <- seq(min(mtcars$wt, na.rm=TRUE), max(mtcars$wt, na.rm=TRUE), length=25)
```

Next, we can make a function that will generate predictions. Because we are going to use `outer()` below, we should have the function take two inputs and `x` and a `y`.  The x-y pairs we are going to pass in are the values of `hp` and `wt` used for the predictions.  The function makes a data frame that has one observation and two variables - `hp` and `wt`.  It uses that new data frame to generate a single prediction from the model using the `predict()` function.

```
predfun <- function(x,y){
  newdat <- data.frame(hp = x, wt=y)
  predict(mod, newdata=newdat)
}
```

Next, we apply that prediction function to the sequences of data we made above.  We use `outer()` the outer-product function to make a 25x25 matrix of predicted values for every combination of `hp.seq` and `wt.seq`.  Wrapping `predfun` in `Vectorize()` prevents errors about replacement length problems.

```
fit <- outer(hp.seq, wt.seq, Vectorize(predfun))
```

Finally, we can put everything together in `plot_ly`.  We use `add_marker()` to add the points and `add_surface` to add the predictions.

```
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~mtcars$hp, y=mtcars$wt, z=mtcars$qsec) %>% 
  add_surface(x = ~hp.seq, y = ~wt.seq, z = t(fit))
```

[image]

Comment: It is working fine, but can you explain how does it work, so that I can vary different parameters to enhance the fit a little bit better,  I particularly could not understand this line: mod <- gam(qsec ~ te(hp) + te(wt) + ti(hp, wt), data=mtcars) and also the prediction function.

Comment: @kolas0202 I added some explanation above.  The `gam()` function fits a generalized additive model.  The RHS specification (~`te(hp) + te(wt) + ti(hp,wt)`) fits a smooth interaction of the two variables.  If you like you could substitute the gam with a loess model: `mod <- loess(qsec ~ hp*wt, data=mtcars)` and the rest of the code would work as intended. I think the takeaway from this, though, is that to plot a smooth surface you have to fit a model to the data.

Comment: can I add formula in the loess function, like we usally do in 2D data, for e.g. mod <- loess(formula = y~ poly(x, 4, raw = TRUE), data=s). Does this works for 3D data too to get the surface fit, mod <- loess(formula = z ~ poly(x,y, 4,5, raw = TRUE), data=s)

Comment: Perhaps, but if you want a polynomial, I would just use `lm(z~poly(x, 4, raw=TRUE) + poly(y, 5, raw=TRUE), data=s)`.  Again, then the rest of the function should work as expected.  This would make an additive model in `x` and `y`, but it would be smooth and non-linear.